# Calculating new Mean and Variance after observation removal

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, mean

I have a random sample of 15 observations and the sample mean is 11.2 and the sample variance is 13.4 but one of the observations of 21.2 was unreliable so I want to remove it and find the sample mean and variance of the remaining 14 observations. I don't have access to the data-set, just the mean and variance of the sample of 15.

I'm unsure of how I would go about solving this.

Comment: What have you tried. What are you unsure of? How is finding the mean and variance of  the sample with one observation removed different from finding the mean and variance of the full sample?

Comment: @BradS. I don't have access to the data-set. I am just told the variance and mean of the sample of 15 and from there I have to work out the new mean and variance after the removal of 21.2.

Comment: Ah....I see. May I suggest that you try to re-word yopur question to make that important fact clear.

Comment: @BradS. I just did, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: This reads like an exercise for a class (and it's a commonly set exercise). Is it?

Comment: @Glen_b It's a Data analysis question I'm unsure as to how to solve.

Comment: That's not a very clear response (I can't tell whether it's related to coursework or not). It's important to be very clear about the source of your question so we don't just answer your homework. See the [help/on-topic] on homework-style questions, which (while indicating that you can ask such questions, adds "*Please mark them with the self-study tag. They get somewhat special treatment, because ultimately you benefit most by finding the solution yourself. The community will try to provide guidance, hints, and useful links.*" ...ctd

Comment: ctd...  in particular you need to do some [search and research](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and you need to show a decent attempt and indicate where you got stuck or you ask a much more specific question about your difficulties. It really looks like you're not putting much effort into solving this (or if you are, you're not showing us any of it)

Answer (score 0):

let's start with the mean...
$$\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$
where, $n=15$ and $\bar x = 11.2$
expand the sum
$$\bar x = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots+x_{n-1}+x_n}{n}$$
without loss of generality, suppose that $x_n$ is the unreliable observation, the one to be removed. Let's put all of the knowns on left hand side of the equation and all of the unknowns on the right hand side....

$$n \bar x - x_n= {x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots+x_{n-1}}$$
and again, we know that $n = 15$, $\bar x = 11.2$ and $x_{15} = 21.2$ 
$$15(11.2) - 21.2= {x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots+x_{14}}$$
We now have an expression for the sum of the "good" observations. In fact, we know their sum...so we can find the mean of the remaining fourteen "good" observations directly
$$\frac{146.8}{14} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{14}{x_i}}{14} = 10.4857 $$

can you apply this same idea to find the variance of the sample with one "bad" observation removed?

Comment: @Poena You accepted the answer and then un-accepted it...why?

Comment: I knew how to calculate the mean already but I'm unsure as to how to use that mean to get that to match the variance.